# Powershell Hashtable Issue

Tags: powershell

I create a small script for accepting a Users ID, First Name, Last Name and then adding that data to a hash table. The problem I have is when I display my hashtable to says the value of the user is System.Object. What am I doing wrong?

```
$personHash = @{}
$userID=""
$firstname=""  
$lastname=""


    While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userID))
    {
        $userID = Read-Host "Enter ID"
    }

    While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($firstname))
    {
        $firstname = Read-Host "Enter First Name"
    }


    While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lastname))
    {
        $lastname = Read-Host "Enter Last Name"
    }


$user = New-Object System.Object
$user | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name ID -value $userID
$user | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name First -value $firstname
$user | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Last -Value $lastname
$personHash.Add($user.ID,$user)

$personHash
```

Comment: You create `$user` as a `System.Object`.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Try `$personHash[$user.ID]` or `$personHash['NameYouEntered']`.  You see `System.Object` because the hashtable contains an object of that type as the value for that entry.  It's a placeholder that says "There's an object here, but it's too complex to display."

Comment: @BaconBits - How do I correct this user to show my user object properly?

Comment: In a hashtable?  You don't.  Not with the way you're doing the object.

Comment: @BaconBits - I think mike z provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when PowerShell displays the contents of a hashtable it just calls ToString on the objects in the table. It doesn't format them using the `DefaultDisplayPropertySet` as it usually does.

One alternative is to use PSCustomObject instead of System.Object like so:

```
$user = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ ID = $userID; First = $firstname; Last = $lastname }
$personHash.Add($user.ID, $user)
```

Then the display will be something like:

```
Name         Value  
----         -----  
1            @{ID=1;First="Mike";Last="Z"}
```

Comment: There's no need to use new-object here. You can merely cast the hashtable to [PSCustomObject].

Answer (score 2):

Use `[PSCustomObject]` to create at type that PowerShell knows how to render to string:

```
$personHash = @{}
$userID=""
$firstname=""  
$lastname=""

While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($userID))
{
    $userID = Read-Host "Enter ID"
}

While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($firstname))
{
    $firstname = Read-Host "Enter First Name"
}

While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lastname))
{
    $lastname = Read-Host "Enter Last Name"
}

$personHash[$userID] = [pscustomobject]@{ID=$userID; First=$firstname; Last=$lastname}
$personHash
```